# Apache rewrite rule with empty get args

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to redirect all urls with ? at the end. For example: `http://example.com/abc?`, but no `http://example.com/abc?a=5` or `http://example.com/abc`.

This doesn`t work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\sH
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This will remove even non-empty query string from URLs

Comment: @Anubhava yes , you are right I fixed the pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NE,R=301,L]
```